# Crash while launching multiple instances of same nodelet

Tags: ros-kinetic, nodelet, cv-bridge, libopencv, shared-ptr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to load a nodelet multiple times. But the node is getting crashed once the second instance of the node let started executing.

Below snippet describes the way I am loading the nodelet.

```
std::string name = ros::this_node::getName() + "instance1";
my_argv.push_back("instance1");
my_argv.push_back("0");
my_argv.push_back("10");
manager.load(name, "myNodelet/exNodelet", remappings, my_argv);


my_argv.clear();
my_argv.push_back("instance2");
my_argv.push_back("0");
my_argv.push_back("10");
name = ros::this_node::getName() + "instance2";
manager.load(disparity_name, "myNodelet/exNodelet", remappings, my_argv);


my_argv.clear();
my_argv.push_back("instance3);
my_argv.push_back("11");
my_argv.push_back("10");
name = ros::this_node::getName() + "instance3";
manager.load(name, "myNodelet/exNodelet", remappings, my_argv);
```

Can anyone give any clue on why the second instance(not instance2. If I launch instance2 first then it will run perfect. The instance, launched 2nd getting crashed.) getting crashed.

**Note:** I am using OpenCV library in my nodelet.

**Edit:**
I have debugged the problem further. I have noticed, when  I commented OpenCV call the nodelet is launched perfectly in the second instance.

Please have a look at the gdb trace below

#0  0x00007f81913e3525 in ?? () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_calib3d3.so.3.1
#1  0x00007f81913e3cd7 in ?? () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_calib3d3.so.3.1
#2  0x00007f81913e679f in ?? () from /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libopencv_calib3d3.so.3.1
#3  0x00007f81ec556cb7 in stereo_vision::stereoReconstruct::process (this=0xff9960, l_image_msg=..., l_info_msg=..., r_image_msg=..., r_info_msg=...)
at /home/swahana/Murali/catkin_ws_nodelets/src/stereo_vision/src/nodelet/stereoReconstruct.cpp:271
#4  0x00007f81ec56f606 in boost::function9<void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&, boost::shared_ptr<message_filters::NullType const> const&>::operator() (a8=..., a7=..., a6=..., a5=..., a4=..., a3=..., a2=..., a1=..., a0=..., this=)
at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:773

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258256/crash-while-launching-multiple-instances-of-same-nodelet/) by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-30**:
Do you absolutely need to use the manager directly (ie: as a local C++ object)? Any reason you can't use the regular nodelet manager node and the service interface provided by it?

**Comment by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) on 2017-03-30**:
The manager used here is a regular nodelet manager.
I have found from the debug information and the trails I have made by commenting OpenCV call, the issue is with the Opencv call not with the ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the issue. I have declared the OpenCV class object as a global variable. This was causing the problem.
Now I made that as a nodelet subclass variable.

---

Originally posted by [mkreddy477](https://answers.ros.org/users/29390/mkreddy477/) with karma: 58 on 2017-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0